# Suitescript nlapiSearchRecord() Multi select filter not working

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Ive got a very basic nlapiSearchRecord function running and as soon as I add a new filter which is a filter on a multi select, it starts to throw errors and wont filter any records.

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_pm_years_manufactured',null,'is','16'))
```

or

```
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_pm_years_manufactured',null,'is','2016'))
```

No matter what I try to apply to it for filtering on a multi select field it simply wont render.

any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

if 16 is the internal id of a year list/record item then

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_pm_years_manufactured',null,'anyof',['16'])
```